# Chaining properties using data from array

Tags: javascript

Unsure if my question's title is correctly worded, please correct me if it's wrong.

I'm using [TypeIt](https://typeitjs.com) to display dialogues. Right away an example of its usage for context:

```js
new TypeIt('#myElement', {
  // options
})
.type("This is a sentence.")
.pause(500)
.type(" A second sentence after waiting 500 milliseconds")
.go();
```

Preview of example on codepen: https://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/yLBawrZ

I'm trying to display a random dialogue from an array but my method results in every dialogue being displayed from the list all at once starting from the first one.

[MY CODE](https://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/yLBaGPL) (Click on the blue bar for dialogue to appear)

Javascript:

```js
var dialogue = new TypeIt('#dialogues', {
    speed: 50,
    waitUntilVisible: true,
    cursor: false
});

var dialogueText = [
    dialogue.type("First line of a dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("Second line of dialogue."),
    dialogue.type("First line of second dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("Second line of dialogue."),
    dialogue.type("First line of third dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("Second line of dialogue."),
    dialogue.type("First line of fourth dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("Second line of dialogue.")
    ];

var refreshDialogueBox = document.querySelector(".dialogue-box");
var dialoguesLength = dialogueText.length - 1;

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var randomDialogue = getRandomInt(dialoguesLength);

refreshDialogueBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    dialogue.reset();
    dialogueText[3].go();
});
```

Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem essentially is your'e creating a **single** `TypeIt` instance, appending all 4 pairs of texts to that single instance, and storing that single instance 4 times in the `dialogueText` array.

I.e. `TypeIt.type()` does not return a new instance, but instead modifies the original instance.

The solution is to simply create 4 instances of `TypeIt`, e.g.

```
let x = () =>
    new TypeIt('#dialogues', {
        speed: 50,
        waitUntilVisible: true,
        cursor: false
    });

var dialogueText = [
    x().type("1.1 First line of a dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("1.2 Second line of dialogue."),
    x().type("2.1 First line of second dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("2.2 Second line of dialogue."),
    x().type("3.1 First line of third dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("3.2 Second line of dialogue."),
    x().type("4.1 First line of fourth dialogue. ").pause(500).break().type("4.2 Second line of dialogue.")
];

var refreshDialogueBox = document.querySelector(".dialogue-box");
var dialoguesLength = dialogueText.length - 1;

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

refreshDialogueBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let dialog = dialogueText[getRandomInt(dialoguesLength)];
    dialog.reset();
    dialog.go();
});
```

https://codepen.io/junvar00/pen/QWLKRyj

P.S. Thanks for including a running and minimal sample of your code, it helps a lot in answering the question!

Comment: This works exactly as I want to! Thank you so much. Also thanks for adding the random number generation inside the event function too, I totally missed that! My js knowledge is still at an amatuer level and still figuring things out :/

I'll just wait for half an hour before I accept your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to have an array of objects with the values you want, not an array of methods.

```
var dialogueText = [
    {firstLine: "First line of a dialogue. ", secondLine: "Second line of dialogue."},
    {firstLine: "First line of second dialogue. ", secondLine: "Second line of dialogue."},
    {firstLine: "First line of third dialogue. ", secondLine: "Second line of dialogue."},
    {firstLine: "First line of fourth dialogue. ", secondLine: "Second line of dialogue."}
];
```

second, you need to generate the random number every time you click, now you are only generating it once so it always returns the same value.

third, to reset the instance, I think you need to declare a new instance inside the function. -and there can be a better way but I didn't read the full documentation of the plugin-

```
refreshDialogueBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }
    var randomDialogue = getRandomInt(dialoguesLength);

    dialogue.reset();
    dialogue.type(dialogueText[randomDialogue].firstLine).pause(500).break().type(dialogueText[randomDialogue].secondLine).go();

    // dialogue.reset();
});
```

Comment: My example is a tad misleading I suppose. Each dialogue would be synced to an audio and the pauses and breaks will vary for each dialogue.